# Salesforce/PHP - Make field read-only after user has entered value

Tags: php, salesforce

In Salesforce I have an account. On that account I have a couple of fields that are populated from the PHP SDK after some processes run in the background. The PHP SDK updates a field on certain conditions, when that happens I also would like to lock down that field to read-only. Can I do this from the PHP SDK?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Salesforce, but this seems to be a bad idea from a usability standpoint. What happens if the user enters an incorrect value?

Comment: There are two systems involved, legacy and the new one. but migration hasn't happened 100% yet. Updating takes place in the new system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want your "lock" on database (or in this case - on Salesforce) level, not on the PHP SDK level. Because otherwise malicious user will just grab Data Loader or Excel Connector and go on with his update bypassing your lock ;)

Try out the Salesforce Validation Rules or (if your logic is complex) a "before update" trigger.

Example validation rule could look like:

condition:

```
AND(
    ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Type),"Technology Partner"),
    ISCHANGED(Type),
    $Profile.Name <> "System Administrator"
)
```

error message to be displayed:

```
After Type has been set to "Technology partner" only Administrators can modify this field.
```

This is just a starting point, feel free to experiment and fine-tune. You can also disable this rule after migration.

Check out the [Validation Rules functions help page](https://na5.salesforce.com/help/doc/user_ed.jsp?section=Customizing&target=customize_functions.htm&loc=help) or **[intro to Validation Rules](http://salesforce.breezecentral.com/customvalidationformulas/)** for more goodies. The [ISCHANGED()](https://na5.salesforce.com/help/doc/user_ed.jsp?section=Customizing&target=customize_functions.htm%23ISCHANGED&loc=help) function should be especially useful for you.

Comment: This looks like what I need, will test and confirm

Comment: Hmm is there a way to say, if blank can edit (Text field), else lock?

Comment: "AND(ISCHANGED(field), LEN(PRIORVALUE(field)) <> 0)" for example. I've decided to examine non-zero length of previous value, but there are many related functions that might suit you better: blankvalue(), nullvalue(), isblank(), isnull().

Comment: Would this validation rule apply to the API user? As I also need to allow the API user to update the record but not a normal user

Comment: Validation rules apply to everyone & no matter how they access the application (web, API etc.). You would have to include the exception for this user (like I did with System Administrator profile) into the rule. Can be based on Role, Profile, username, anything really. Explore the variables starting with "$" in the Validation Rule editor in the "Insert field" popup.